# How To Stop Desired Keyboards/Mouse Keys On A WebPage?

Tags: javascript, keyboard, key, mouse, mousewheel

I have a problem. I want to stop some keyboard and mouse keys on my webpage through using pure JavaScript, no JQuery. How can I do this? Here is my desired keys list that I want to stop?

- Keyboard Up Arrow
- Keyboard Down Arrow
- Keyboard PageUp Key
- Keyboard PageDown Key
- Keyboard Home Key
- Keyboard End Key
- Keyboard CTRL + Numpad 2 Key
- Keyboard CTRL + Numpad 8 Key
- Keyboard CTRL + Keyboard U Key
- Mouse Wheel Up
- Mouse Wheel Down

Comment: Stop, as in prevent the actions that would normally take place when the user takes those actions? Good grief, why? That'd annoy the living daylights out of me, and I'd leave as soon as I could figure out how, with my crippled keyboard and mouse.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta Thanks in advance. Actually I am working on a project so I want to stop these keys to work when visitor hit them because I added all these function manually on links on my project. Waiting to see the code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my desired code and its working. So I am also sharing here thinking that it can help you too. First see the live DEMO at **http://jsfiddle.net/CQLpV/1/** then garb the code from below.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    // Space Bar And Arrow Keys Are Addto To Stop Working
    if([32, 37, 38, 39, 40].indexOf(e.keyCode) > -1) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}, false);
</script>
```

You can get more keyboard keys characters codes from [**All Keyboard Keys Char Codes List**](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes).

Answer (score 0):

What you are going to want to do is to prevent the default action when those keys are hit by listening to the events...

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {

   if(e.which == 91 /* up arrow */ || e.which == 93 /* down arrow */ ... add all the keys here)
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
   }
}
```

Then just do the same for the mouse wheel char codes.

Comment: Are these Ok? [Char Codes List](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes)

Comment: Got it. See my answer and DEMO... :)